# In eclipse jaspersoft studio plugin, how to edit an existing data adapter?

Tags: eclipse, jaspersoft-studio

I have a simple question. I have been searching everywhere including the official jasper forum but no answers so far. I need to know where can I find the existing data adapters for jasper (I am using **jaspersoft studio plugin** for eclipse).The reason for this is because I need to update one of my existing adapters.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I found it by trial and error. SO there is a menu item called repository explorer under Window > Show View > JasperReports > Repository Explorer in eclipse. Click that and it will show a new tab on the your eclipse IDE called "Repository Explorer". All of the existing data adapters are there.

capture of Repository Explorer

[image]